# Setting composite drawing mode causing black holes/patches on NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawing, quartz-2d

I wanted to draw a shape, over it I wanted to draw the smaller transparent shape.

```
-(void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    //clear everything
    {
        [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:dirtyRect] fill];
    }


    NSBezierPath    *thePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: self.bounds];
    [thePath setLineWidth: 30];
    [[NSColor blueColor] set];
    [thePath stroke];

    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setCompositingOperation: NSCompositeCopy];
    [[NSColor clearColor] set];
    [thePath setLineWidth: 4];
    [thePath stroke];
}
```

[image: As a result of above program I'm getting the Blue Oval and a black Oval at the center of blue Oval.]

I've also tried it with an NSImage forst and then on view, but still getting the same result.

```
-(void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    //clear everything
    {
        [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:dirtyRect] fill];
    }


    NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:self.frame.size];

    [image lockFocus];

    //clear everything
    {
        [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:dirtyRect] fill];
    }

    NSBezierPath    *thePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: self.bounds];
    [thePath setLineWidth: 30];
    [[NSColor blueColor] set];
    [thePath stroke];

    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setCompositingOperation: NSCompositeCopy];
    [[NSColor clearColor] set];
    [thePath setLineWidth: 4];
    [thePath stroke];

    [image unlockFocus];

    [image drawInRect:self.frame fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The oval appears black because windows are opaque by default. You've successfully cut an oval track in your window, but because the window is opaque, without an industrial laser to cut the same oval in your monitor, your Mac has to show *some* color there instead. The color it shows is the color of `clearColor`: black.

The solution is to set the window's `opaque` to `NO`.

The default is `YES`, which is nice and efficient but (well, actually, *because*) it prevents other windows' contents from showing through. Setting it to `NO` will allow you to see what is behind the window through that thin oval track. (It'll work better if you fill the oval, giving yourself a larger window in the… er… window.)

[image: This is how it looks with the window's opaque turned off.]

(Why does it look like the track is filled with gray? That's the window's shadow you're seeing there. When you try it for real, you'll be able to see the other windows on your system through the track as you move the window around.)

Comment: Thanks for superb explanation.
Just wanted to know, is there any way to draw transparent shape over a solid shape, and the result should not display window shadow or black holes.

Comment: @Omkar: “transparent” and “should not display window shadow” are at odds, since transparency lets you see what's behind the window, and the shadow is behind the window. You can turn the window's shadow off, but then it won't be visible around the window, either.